# How to divide a 3d model into a sandwitch stack?

Tags: modeling

I need to slice a 3d model of a complex object to a regular interval 2d plane stack.

How can I sequentially extract planes y0, y1,y2.. from the complex object that doesn't contain interior faces?

Comment: Maybe something like in this answer might help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91786/model-as-multiple-unique-thin-sheets/91788#91788 (just skip the solidify modifier)