# Volumetric slicing in Blender

Tags: modeling, volumetrics

Is there a way to slice a 3D object into planes (see attached image), merge them and export it as a single .obj?

I do not want to see the parts of the object that are left between planes, I just want to see the slices. Kind of like a tomography.

I saw a video of guy make this in Houdini, is it possible to do in Blender?

Link to the video: https://youtu.be/4ggS6G9HIh8?t=685

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1853/animating-slicing-up-an-object

Comment: FYI this is also the technique used by the Eevee render engine to approximate volume objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Model as multiple unique thin sheets](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91786/model-as-multiple-unique-thin-sheets)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get a similar result with a Boolean modifier

1. Create your slicing planes (you can array them using Array modifier)
2. Add a *Boolean Modifier > Intersect* to your object
3. Target the slicing planes

<sup>I hid the slicing planes in the gif, so the result is better visible</sup>
[image]

For more detail refer to the following links:

[How can I slice an object horizontally into equal pieces?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39510/how-can-i-slice-an-object-horizontally-into-equal-pieces/39519#39519)

[Model as multiple unique thin sheets](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91786/model-as-multiple-unique-thin-sheets/91788#91788)

[How do I create slices of a topographical mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62874/how-do-i-create-slices-of-a-topographical-mesh?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: apologies? I don't understand.

Comment: @susu I know how much you don't like seeing Booleans :)).

Comment: Not really, I dislike booleans as a lazy way to avoid proper modelling, and believing that there are magic tools to fix the outcome of poorly planned topology. Booleans have a time and a place. They can be a great tool when used properly, and your answer is a good example of one.

Comment: Got it now :). Thanks for the edit btw, I was sure there were some dupes already.