# How to slice a 3D object into multiple 2D images?

Tags: 3d-view

I have a 3D object (Rubik's cube) shown below:

[image]

I would like to slice it into many 2D images, for example 20 pieces, then save all the 2D images individually for image post-processing. But I am very new to Blender, I tried to look into Boolean and Array Modifier, but it only copies the 3D object and generates the same one, is there any suggestions to slice a 3D object?

Comment: When you say slice the object, do you mean something like viewing cross-sections of it? Like an MRI scan?

Comment: If you want something like @TheKalaakaar assumes, have a look at the _Bisect_ operator. Go to edit mode, select all faces and adjust the operation. You can for example discard one side of the cut and fill the cross-sections.

Comment: Thank you guys for the information! Actually, I would like to mimic what they did to slice the 3D object and be able to save each slice (2D image) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58153/create-cross-sections-and-2d-planes-in-blender                   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/207385/volumetric-slicing-in-blender

Comment: Do you want to have an image sequence where the slices show the shape/silhouette of the object or really rendered with all materials as if it was sliced to pieces?